# A program for prime-factorizing any given number

Tags: python, prime-factoring

```
n = 600851475143 
i = 2

while i * i < n:
    while n%i == 0:
        n = n / i
    i = i + 1

print (n)
```

This is a program in python that finds the largest prime factor of any given number. I was wondering if there is a way to modify it so that one can find all the prime factors instead of just the largest one. I was thinking since this program is fast and neat, is there a way to add a few lines of code that changes it in what I need, which is all the prime factors?

Comment: Are you asking how to change it so `n` can be any number?

Comment: What have you tried so far? It should be straightforward to create a list and add `i` to it whenever the division by n is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple program to factor integers:

```
Python 2.7.5+ (default, Sep 17 2013, 15:31:50) 
[GCC 4.8.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def factors(n):
...     f, fs = 2, []
...     while f * f <= n:
...         if n % f == 0:
...             fs.append(f)
...             n = n / f
...         else:
...             f = f + 1
...     fs.append(n)
...     return fs
... 
>>> factors(600851475143)
[71, 839, 1471, 6857]
```

There are better ways to factor integers, but that's enough to get you started. If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend [this essay](https://programmingpraxis.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/primenumbers.pdf) at my blog.